# Route email via Exchange Server 2007 based on rules. Possible?

Tags: exchange-2007

I have specific mail that comes via SMTP:

```
From: somespecificuser@domain.com
Subject: [managers][users]Hello!
```

I want to set a rule in exchange server itself that will route message into appropriate boxes based on what subject line contains. So for example this message should be forwarded to 
managers@domain.com and users@domain.com

Is it possible with Exchange Server 2007?

Comment: The answer will be Exchange Server version specific.  Is this 2003, 2007, or 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Transport Rules on the Org Hub Role?

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/transport-rules-exchange-server-2007.html