# Forward mails based on sender email address and subject directly on Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, forwarding, mail-forwarding

I go the task to forward mails directly on the Exchange 2007 Server. The emails come from an external sender (is always the same) and depending on the subject the emails should be forwarded to two different internal recipients. Is this possible? I found out that I can redirect all messages but not such specific rules with sender and subject.

The best idea I have is to create a new mailbox on which all new incoming mails should be send. This mailbox than forwards all mails to a group.

What options do I have?

I found this question: [Route email via Exchange Server 2007 based on rules. Possible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/358485/route-email-via-exchange-server-2007-based-on-rules-possible)  Would it be possible to set up a transport rule with an external sender? Do I have to create a mail enabled contact for the external sender?

Comment: forward mails FROM an external sender to where?  internally?  back out to an external recipient? What are you trying to accomplish (give an example)?

Comment: @TheCleaner: The emails come from an external sender (is always the same) and depending on the subject the emails should be forwarded to two different internal recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, then this is very easy to do.

You actually have two different ways to accomplish it.

The easiest is with transport rules, as you linked to.

Simply setup the transport rule (walk through the wizard in the Hub Transport section of the Org).  You don't need a mail enabled contact.  Choose mail coming in from "people" and change that field to "external address" and type in the email address it is coming from.

Then also check the box for specifying a subject and define that.

Then choose to forward to a particular person/address and choose the right internal recipient.

REPEAT/create another transport rule the exact same way but with different subject and different internal person.

The alternative way would be to use a public folder to receive the mail (all mail would have to be incoming to a particular smtp address on that public folder) and then use the PF assistant to create rules based on subject and then forward appropriately.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How can I change the field to "external address"? I don't see any option. What does "PF assistant" mean? Public folder?

Comment: I don't have 2007, just 2010, so I'm hoping the menus are still the same.  New Transport rule, Step1/Conditions, check "from people", then at the bottom click the "people" link, should have an "Add" choice at the top with a small drop arrow next to the word "Add", choose the arrow and there should be "External E-Mail Address".

Comment: Note: if the only option in 2007 is to choose from the GAL, and not like my last comment, then simply create a simple contact with that external email address and choose it instead.

Comment: I set up the rules (with the created contact because I can't see the option) and I'll test it. Thanks.